# Remote SQL SERVER run slow with asp net application

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linq, network-programming

i have an application that runs normally in my first website.

If i move this applicatio to another server, but i don't move db (that remains to server 1), it runs very slowly to retrive data from sql.

The problem is only network or is there any issue in my code?
I use ADO.NET with LINQ...

Thank

Comment: This is why you should develop in a similar environment as what you expect to have in production.

Comment: my app was developed in the same environment as production but now i have to separate db and app

Answer (score 1):

If they were residing on the same server before and now their not, then yeah it's almost certainly a network issue. Are the servers housed in the same location? I'm taking a guess here since I don't have adequate information, but there's a chance that your intranet isn't configured correctly or you're using an external IP's. In that case one or both of the request and response are being sent out over the internet when they could be using your or your company's internal network to communicate.

Comment: yes this is my situation. i only can try to improve my network speed. my query are very small... i use external ip. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Profile your queries. See how much time it takes to execute each. If your queries return fast, the problem might be your front-end code or the network.

You can log your Linq queries to console (or a Textwriter, for example). Something like:

```
dataContext.Log = Console.Out;
```

Then run the queries in SQL Server and see how efficient they are. Do they use indexes? Do they perform table scans? etc.

Comment: Are they returning more fields and/or more records than you actually need? The more data flows across the network the slower it is. Any query with a join and select * for instance is wasting server and network resources.

Comment: no, my querys are like "var q = (from c in db.Table where c.Attivo = 1 select new { ... });" or this "P_FTIC.entities.Contatti C = db.Contatti.Where(x => x.IDContatto == _id && x.Attivo == 1).SingleOrDefault();"...